# Manually open a nyroModal Gallery

Tags: jquery, gallery, nyromodal

After reading the doc, I managed to make manual calls to open url (images) with the following code

```
$.nmManual(this.href);
```

But now I'd like to do a manual call to the nyroModal gallery filter without any luck so far. I tried to push the filter `gallery` in the `.nmManual()` callback but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this need with manual call and I used this workaround:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<?php $i=0; ?>
<?php foreach ($Gallery as $item): ?>
<?php if ($item->hasPhoto()): ?>
<a id="photo<?php echo $i ?>" href="<?php echo $item->getRelativePhotoPath() ?>" class="photo_gallery" title="<?php echo $item->getCaption() ?>" rel="gal"></a>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {   
    // #photo_gallery is the css selector of the anchor link used to start the gallery
    if ($('#photo_gallery').length != 0 && $('.photo_gallery').length != 0)
    {
        $('.photo_gallery').nyroModal();        

        $('#photo_gallery').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();     

            $('#photo0').click();
        });
    }  
});
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks for your input, but I am using the manual call because I want to use the nyroModal plugin on a `live()` event, and unfortunately the `.nyroModal()` call does only work once, when the DOM is ready (like in your example).

Comment: `.nyroModal()` attachs the event handler, the gallery starts trough `$('#photo0').click()` where #photo0 is the first image. Of course I don't know your code, just asking myself if you can perform this type of behaviour using a `live()`